# How to navigate with .lua to a directory above

Tags: path, lua, directory

I have something like this.

```
/config.lua
/client/init.lua
```

How can I include the `config.lua` with `include()` or `dofile()`?
Lg

Comment: `dofile"/config.lua"` doesn't work for you?

Comment: no: http://puu.sh/5PTeZ.png

Comment: Odd. You're on Linux and the root of your filesystem has config.lua? So if you do "ls /*.lua" you see config.lua listed?

Comment: You can find out what your working directory is when running your script. Use something like `os.execute("cd")` or `popen` as suggested below. Once you know the current working dir you can construct the path to the target script relative to that directory.

Comment: well, the problem is I run the scripts from a Just Cause 2 MP Server, so nothing really happens when I'm trying to do that. Altough I don't understand atm what exactly you mean, so it would be nice if you can explain it retard-like. thanks

Comment: Can you use `print` or `io.write` in your script from this program? If so, try `print(io.popen('cd', 'r'):read'*a')`, and it should display where the current working directory is.

Comment: http://puu.sh/5QToB.png its shows this

Answer (score 5):

You can (and probably should) do this with `require` by adding `../?.lua` to `package.path`, like so:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";../?.lua"
require "config"
```

See the [require](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) and [package.path](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.path) docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with [`dofile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-dofile). (*However, there is no* `include` *function in Lua.*) As you may have noticed, you can't do this with [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-require):

```
local cfg = require'../config'
```

`require` typically works from the directory of the initial script in a one-way direction, and any required modules which require their own modules must use *relative* names from that starting point to work properly.

**I.e.**, if you have the following structure:

```
--+ main.lua          requires 'lib.test1'
  +-- lib/test1.lua   requires 'test2'
  +-- lib/test2.lua
```

`test1.lua` will **fail** to require `test2` because it cannot be found from the initial directory. `lib.test2` is the appropriate module name here. I'm not sure if there are any good patterns for this, short of writing your own stateful `require`, but it's helpful to know about when writing library code.

Perhaps it's a bad sign when it comes to this.

---

Going back to the question, you could make an exemption for your `config` file in `package.loaded`. This is effectively loading it manually:

```
package.loaded.config = dofile'../config.lua'
-- ...
local cfg = require'config'
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for you answer, but it doesn't work. (my config is named job_config): http://puu.sh/5PWb3.png the structure looks like that: (in both folders there is a .lua who needs to include the config) http://puu.sh/5PWdB.png

Comment: Where is your current directory in relation to `job_config.lua`? You should be able to determine this by printing `io.popen('cd', 'r'):read'*a'` somewhere or running `os.execute'cd'` in a terminal.